# MVC3 controller action redirect to URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this string "**/TrackMyJob/JobTasksInvolvedPartiesDetail?jobtaskobjid=638e17c9-8d0a-4da4-866f-098c619bab63**".
I got the above from `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery`, is it possible my controller to redirect there ? if yes how ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Redirect`<sup>docs</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method of the controller.

But why would you want to do that ? Isn't that url supported by your routes ?

Comment: I need to return to different views, with different signatures based on from where this view is called, so the caller is passing his signature so that the view can return there. The routing is working, the redirect goes through my routes.